# Mapbox Icons/Markers "BearingSnap" or Snap to Position

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl, mapbox-gl-js

Is there a way to move icons/markers to a certain location where it will then "snap" to the location?

For example, chess games on the computer where when you move a chess piece to the correct square, it will snap to that position when you let go of the piece near/around the square.

So what I want is to move a marker or an icon to a certain location, let's say the capital of California, and the marker will "snap" to the location that I want when I move it and let go of the marker near the location. But I also want to still be able to move the marker if I want to.

I know Mapbox gl has [bearingSnap](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/) which snaps the map back to north after the user rotates the map but I can't find anything for just icons/markers and I don't believe I can use `bearingSnap` for it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Turfs](http://turfjs.org) distance function: `turf.distance(pt1, pt2)` to measure distances between 2 points. If then the calculated distance is under a certain threshold, you can set the location of your dragging point to the location of your snap point.

I have you a working example in a jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/andi_lo/nmc4kprn/

```js
function onMove(e) {
  if (!isDragging) return;
  var coords = e.lngLat;

  // Set a UI indicator for dragging.
  canvas.style.cursor = 'grabbing';

  // Update the Point feature in `geojson` coordinates
  // and call setData to the source layer `point` on it.
  geojson.features[0].geometry.coordinates = [coords.lng, coords.lat];
  map.getSource('point').setData(geojson);
  
  let snapTo = map.getSource('snap')._data;
  
  turf.featureEach(snapTo, (feature) => {
    let dist = turf.distance(feature, turf.point([coords.lng, coords.lat]));
    console.log(dist);
    // if the distance of the dragging point is under a certain threshold
    if (dist < 500) {
     // set the location of the dragging point to the location of the snapping point
     geojson.features[0].geometry.coordinates = feature.geometry.coordinates;
  map.getSource('point').setData(geojson);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: This may be what I've been looking for... Just wondering would this also work for multiple points and locations? i.e. Points A, B, C would be able to go to respectively Locations Aa, Bb, Cc?

Comment: Not out of the box. You will need to save the last clicked point to know which one is getting dragged by the mouse. I updated the example to support multiple snap points and multiple location points see here: https://jsfiddle.net/andi_lo/nmc4kprn/5/

Answer (score -1):

This is a feature you can and should implement upstream of GL JS. When you construct the coordinate of the marker or GeoJSON feature, snap it to the desired grid.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still pretty new to Mapbox. Can you elaborate that a little bit more? Thanks.

Comment: He is not talking about a snap grid nor does your answer provide any information of a possible solution