# Snapping a draggable point to a vector tile set line in Mapbox GL JS using turf.js

Tags: javascript, gis, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, turfjs

I'm trying to snap a draggable point to a vector tileset that consists of lines, but I'm not sure if it's possible using a Mapbox vector tileset.

It's essentially the equivalent of this point snapping example that uses turf.js 
https://jsfiddle.net/andi_lo/nmc4kprn/5/
which is outlined in the following stack overflow post:
[Mapbox Icons/Markers "BearingSnap" or Snap to Position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39417535/mapbox-icons-markers-bearingsnap-or-snap-to-position/44798270)

I've amended a basic Mapbox draggable point example to query the rendered features contained in the tileset. I'm just not sure how to incorporate the measuring and snapping functionality into it. I can see in the console log that the coordinates for the feature that I intersect are returned. Any ideas?

```js
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1Ijoic2luc3ctc2NpIiwiYSI6ImNqajd6MHYyZjEyZzUzcnBlNnM1OHFmdXoifQ.ZBT_-d26dSFur2oWzXAQvA';

var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
  container: 'map',
  style: 'mapbox://styles/sinsw-sci/cjl1x0v4489j32qp2nd9swywc',
  center: [151.206, -33.865],
  zoom: 17
});


var canvas = map.getCanvasContainer();


var geojson = {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [{
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {},
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [151.206, -33.865]
    }
  }]
};


function onMove(e) {
  var coords = e.lngLat;

  // Set a UI indicator for dragging.
  canvas.style.cursor = 'grabbing';

  // Update the Point feature in `geojson` coordinates
  // and call setData to the source layer `point` on it.
  geojson.features[0].geometry.coordinates = [coords.lng, coords.lat];
  map.getSource('point').setData(geojson);

  var features = map.queryRenderedFeatures(e.point, {
    layers: ['snapTo']
  });

  // console.log(features);

  // Change point and cursor style as a UI indicator
  // and set a flag to enable other mouse events.
  if (features.length) {
    console.log(features);
    canvas.style.cursor = 'move';
    isCursorOverPoint = true;
    map.dragPan.disable();
  } else {
    map.setPaintProperty('point', 'circle-color', '#3887be');
    canvas.style.cursor = '';
    isCursorOverPoint = false;
    map.dragPan.enable();
  }


}

function onUp(e) {
  var coords = e.lngLat;
  canvas.style.cursor = '';

  // Unbind mouse/touch events
  map.off('mousemove', onMove);
  map.off('touchmove', onMove);
}

map.on('load', function() {

  // Add a single point to the map
  map.addSource('point', {
    "type": "geojson",
    "data": geojson
  });

  map.addLayer({
    "id": "point",
    "type": "circle",
    "source": "point",
    "paint": {
      "circle-radius": 10,
      "circle-color": "#3887be"
    }
  });


  map.addSource('snap', {
    type: 'vector',
    url: 'mapbox://mapbox.mapbox-streets-v7'
  });



  map.addLayer({
    id: 'snapTo',
    type: 'line',
    source: 'snap',
    'source-layer': 'road',
    'paint': {
      "line-color": "#2AAAFF",
      "line-opacity": 0.5,
      'line-width': 1
    }
  });








  // When the cursor enters a feature in the point layer, prepare for dragging.
  map.on('mouseenter', 'point', function() {
    map.setPaintProperty('point', 'circle-color', '#3bb2d0');
    canvas.style.cursor = 'move';
  });

  map.on('mouseleave', 'point', function() {
    map.setPaintProperty('point', 'circle-color', '#3887be');
    canvas.style.cursor = '';
  });

  map.on('mousedown', 'point', function(e) {
    // Prevent the default map drag behavior.
    e.preventDefault();

    canvas.style.cursor = 'grab';

    map.on('mousemove', onMove);
    map.once('mouseup', onUp);
  });

  map.on('touchstart', 'point', function(e) {
    if (e.points.length !== 1) return;

    // Prevent the default map drag behavior.
    e.preventDefault();

    map.on('touchmove', onMove);
    map.once('touchend', onUp);
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset='utf-8' />
  <title>Snap point to vector tileset</title>
  <meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />
  <script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.48.0/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
  <link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.48.0/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    
    #map {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      width: 100%;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id='map'></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems possible to me.

You'll need to make two major changes from that Point example.

First, use `queryRenderedFeatures()` to fetch all the source vector features that are candidates for snapping to. You will probably want to pass a bounding box around the current mouse location, to limit how far you look for candidates. You will also want to pass a filter for the right layer, and probably limit it to `["==", "$type", "LineString"]`

Second, while iterating over every returned line feature, use Turf's `nearestPointOnLine()` to both calculate the distance to each line, and find the actual nearest point on that line. Something like:

```
var nearestPoint;
turf.featureEach(snapTo, (feature) => {
    var point = turf.nearestPointOnLine(feature, turf.point([coords.lng, coords.lat]));
    // if the distance of the dragging point is under a certain threshold
    if (!nearestPoint || point.properties.dist < nearestPoint.properties.dist) {
      nearestPoint = point;
    }
  });

if (nearestPoint) {
      // do whatever you do, now that you have the closest point
}
```